# Как вытащить выполненное условие в переменную?

Tags: python, переменные, условия

```py
if int(user_input[7:10]) in range(100, 151):
    print('You were born in East Tallinn Central Hospital or Pelgulinna Maternity Hospital (Tallinn)')
elif int(user_input[7:10]) in range(161, 221):
    print('You were born in Rapla-, Loksa- or Hiiumaa Hospital')
```

У меня есть вот такие 2 условия, как мне вытащить то условие, которое выполнилось - в переменную?

по типу

region = "выполненное условие"

region = "You were born in Rapla-, Loksa- or Hiiumaa Hospital"

P.S user_input - переменная, куда вводится личный код или исикукод(Эстония), по которому можно определить больницу, в которой родился человек.

Answer (score 1):

Например, с помощью конструкции:

```
if var in range(n):
    region = "Rapla-, Loksa- or Hiiumaa"
elif var in range(n, n + k):
    region = "..."
print(f"You were born in {region} Hospital")
```

В таком случае переменная `region` остаётся со значением, которое в ней сохранено.